# PHP filter and replace specific word in string

Tags: php

Original String

```
ROUND(({NOPAY_COUNT} * ({TOTAL_BASIC_SALARY}/24)),2)
```

I want to filter word within '{' & '}' replace word with '$'

```
ROUND(($NOPAY_COUNT * ($TOTAL_BASIC_SALARY/24)),2)
```

Comment: well, ok and what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried with "str_word_count(ROUND(({NOPAY_COUNT} * ({TOTAL_BASIC_SALARY}/24)),2),1,'{_}');" but i don't want to convert ROUND word.

Comment: can you please edit your answer and add this snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use preg_replace() once:

```
<?php
$string = 'ROUND(({NOPAY_COUNT} * ({TOTAL_BASIC_SALARY}/24)),2)';
$string = preg_replace("/{(.+?)}/", "\$$1", $string);
echo $string; //ROUND(($NOPAY_COUNT * ($TOTAL_BASIC_SALARY/24)),2)
```

see your self: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ddG

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_replace()` twice:

```
<?php
$string = 'ROUND(({NOPAY_COUNT} * ({TOTAL_BASIC_SALARY}/24)),2)';
$string = preg_replace('/}/', '', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/{/', '$', $string);
echo $string; //ROUND(($NOPAY_COUNT * ($TOTAL_BASIC_SALARY/24)),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $NOPAY_COUNT = 1;
  $TOTAL_BASIC_SALARY = 1;
  $str = "ROUND(({NOPAY_COUNT} * ({TOTAL_BASIC_SALARY}/24)),2);";
  $str = str_replace("{", "$" , $str);
  $str = str_replace("}", "" , $str);
  eval("echo ".$str);
```